# How do I avoid my picture gets too blurry when compressed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, compression, facebook

I have tried everything I can think of to avoid my page profile picture getting blurry , but no matter how small I resize it (resized it to width of 180px - still blurred), it still gets blurry.

Anyone got some ideas?

[[image: my profile picture]]

Comment: As you're seeing in the answers, this really depends on the software being used to do the resize (and the code that it's using).  For similar reasons it also depends on the specific image and image format.

Comment: Note that "compression" does not mean "make smaller in pixel dimensions"

Comment: I know. I resize the picture to make the file size smaller to avoid Facebook compressing it. It didn't help tough. :)

Comment: What you're calling blurry is just the reality of reducing the resolution of an image with as much detail in it as yours. The only real way to avoid this is to redraw the image at the desired resolution. Sometimes you can get better results at reduced resolutions using the [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) vector graphics format if you have drawing tools that support it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is specific to a website (Facebook, see comments in answers below) and may or may not still be a current problem.

Answer (score 2):

If it converts to JPG and compresses it enough it's always going to have some blur for graphics like this:
[image: PNG vs JPEG]
image thanks to Robert MacLean from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/53600/jpeg-vs-png-vs-bmp-vs-gif) post but originated from [Louis Brandy](https://superuser.com/questions/53600/jpeg-vs-png-vs-bmp-vs-gif).

Answer (score 1):

- Resize it yourself. Most image manipulation programs can do better than Facebook.
- Convert to true-color before resizing; some programs might be trying too hard to remain within the 256-color limit of GIF format.
- Try applying "Sharpen" or similar effects after the resize.

[image: 180px wide]

Comment: Didn't get any better. Look at this: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174885_124642680942773_6114247_n.jpg

But thanks for your try!

Comment: @Andreas: So it's caused by JPEG compression... JPEG is really unsuited for such images. Could you try http://i.imgur.com/yMSHS.jpg (already in JPEG format) and see if Facebook mangles it too?

Comment: Didn't help either. Still blurry. :( 
http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/174864_124642680942773_5636881_n.jpg

Comment: @Andreas: You'll have to give up, then. It seems that Facebook is re-compressing all images irrespective of original format. And with JPEG, a logo like that will look ugly even at 95% quality.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Paint.NET to be good at resizing. This is at 180px - how does it look?
[image: resized]

---

**comment:**  This is an interesting problem actually.  The heavy compression used by Facebook has introduced an unacceptable level of artifacts despite actually increasing the size of the file.  Side by side, the original smaller file is visibly superior:

[image: resized] [image: facebook version]

but Facebook's version is half as big again, so it can't be purely using size as a metric.

I'm afraid I can't suggest a better approach other than trial and error but I'm interested to see how or if you solve it!

Comment: Gets converted to JPEG and blurry: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/162051_124642680942773_4539340_n.jpg

But thanks for your try

Answer (score 1):

If facebook is converting your upload to JPEG, and you have no control over it, then you are out of luck: there is no solution. JPEG is really meant for photographs and randomly-colored adjacent pixels. Line art or limited-color-set artwork is better rendered with PNG or GIF.

If facebook allows you to keep the image as gif, do that, if they only allow you to set compression, set it to highest possible quality.

Comment: Facebook gives no control of the format nor the compression. All you've got is a browse-button and an upload button.

Comment: then there is no solution other than picking another image